# ARM assembly language menu not working

Tags: assembly, arm

```
/*menu_prompt*/
.balign 4
menu_prompt: .asciz "Choose which problem.\nType 1 for Problem 1\nType 2 for Pr$
/*scanner*/
.balign 4
scan_pattern_int: .asciz "%d"
scan_read: .word 0
.balign 4
return: .word 0


.global main
 main:
    ldr r0, address_of_return
    str lr, [r1]

    ldr r0, address_of_menu_prompt
    bl printf

    ldr r0, address_of_scan_pattern_int
    ldr r1, address_of_scan_read
    bl scanf
    ldr r1, [r1]
    str lr, [r1]

    ldr r0, address_of_menu_prompt
    bl printf

    ldr r0, address_of_scan_pattern_int
    ldr r1, address_of_scan_read
    bl scanf
    ldr r1, [r1]
    cmp r1, #1
    beq in_prob_1
    cmp r1, #2
    beq in_prob_2
    cmp r1, #3
    beq in_prob_3
in_prob_1:
    mov r0, #100
    bal end
in_prob_2:
    mov r0, #200
    bal end
in_prob_3:
    mov r0, #300
    bal end
end:
    ldr lr, address_of_return 
    ldr lr, [lr]                     
    bx lr

address_of_menu_prompt: .word menu_prompt
address_of_scan_pattern_int: .word scan_pattern_int
address_of_scan_read: .word scan_read
address_of_return: .word return
```

after i run the program no matter which input i choose (1,2, or 3) echo$? always shows that r0 holds 139, i'm not sure why.  if i choose 1 r0 should hold 100, 2 r0 should hold 200, 3 and r0 should hold 300.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` doesn't need to leave the contents of `r1` as you've passed per ARM Procedure Call Standard. You should reload `r1` after branching to `scanf`.